# What does this hex value mean in source column within NETMON?

Tags: networking, security, sniffing, icmp

I am using NETMON to try and figure out why my local network is running so slow. I think it may be related to a system logged into it, but in order to not draw attention to my task i have been snooping traffic using NETMON for windows 8. I have determined the source of the problem is a flood attack, but i am having a hard time tracing the source and destination.

In NETMON, the source simply states `SA: 002129 9A87R5` and the destination is `DA: *BROADCAST`. Can anyone help me decipher what this means? I am thinking it is encrypted, but what sort of protocol would this be? The pings are going out about 7 times per second consistently, and is really clogging bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

That source address looks like a MAC address.  The 00:21:29 portion is used by Cisco-Linksys, and the 9A:87:R5 portion would be the specific device.  And it's not a ping, it's a broadcast of some sort.

Comment: what sort of broadcast would this be? it seems to be happening very frequently..

Comment: Try an `arp -a` and see if that gives you an IP address.  It could be something simple like (wild guessing) some autoconfig protocol like UPnP.  Are you sure that something happening 7 times a second is affecting your bandwidth?  That's really not that frequent, especially if each packet is only a kilobyte or two, that would be on the order of 7 KB a second, or roughly what you could move with a good modem from 1998.

Comment: No idea; I'd need more info.  The packet data might help.  Also, do you know what Linksys devices are plugged into the network?  I assume this is a wired network?  And out of interest, what makes you think the local network is slow?

Comment: A broadcast 7 times a second is too much in my opinion, once per seven seconds is also too much: unless you're tossing network devices back and forth onto the network all the time and need to have them discovered in a blink of an eye. Assuming an otherwise unused network. 
A tip in context: Google "Wireshark" - this is a free tool to monitor and capture network traffic. http://www.wireshark.org/news/20060607.html

Answer (score 0):

This is a WIFI broadcast beacon. It's usually sent every 100ms.

```
SA: 002129 9A87R5
```

This means: Source Address: 00:21:29:9A:87:R5 (note that 'R' is not a valid value; it's probably an 'A'. This address is a MAC address; the first part is the manufacturer (Which is [Cisco](http://macaddress.webwat.ch/hwaddr/00:21:29) in this case; e.g. your router), the 2nd part is the unique device identificator.

```
DA: *BROADCAST.
```

This means Destination Address: Anyone :)

It's just the router broadcasting its existence to the world. A normal WiFi router does this 10 times a second; it doesn't really take up any bandwith, so don't worry.

> In infrastructure networks, access points (not radio NICs) periodically send beacons. You can set the beacon interval through the access point configuration screen. In general, the beacon interval is set to 100ms, which provides good performance for most applications.

You can check [this WikiPedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beacon_frame) for a small summary, which also references the 100ms interval.

If you want, you can get a detailed explanation about WiFi beacons [here](https://supportforums.cisco.com/document/52391/80211-frames-starter-guide-learn-wireless-sniffer-traces).

Comment: Please expand and put the pertinent details from the article in your answer.